# Adding a class to all the images in the webpage except for a particular <div> using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So I want to add a class to all the images in the webpage except for a particular `<div>`. I have made this code that will add a class to all the images in the webpage:

```
$(function(){
    $('img').addClass('posts');
});
```

I need a similar code that does the vice-versa.

Comment: whether the div has a class or id

Comment: `$('img:not(div.class img)').addClass('posts');` - if the dic has id, then `$('img:not(#divid img)').addClass('posts');`

Comment: @Zack, Can you add the code of html about the image which need to be exceptional?Can you be more specific?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cs9asjhs/4/ I need the class to be applied to all the images but except for the one within <div class="posts">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `.not()` method:

```
$(function(){
    $('img').not('.posts img').addClass('aden');
});
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "do the vice-versa". Are you saying you want to remove the `posts` class from those images, or add it *just* to the images within that div?

Comment: this is not what i asked. I want a class to be applied to all the images in the website except for the images under a particular <div>. https://jsfiddle.net/cs9asjhs/4/ here the image inside <div class="posts" > should not get the class applied to it.

Comment: @Zack Yes, it is what you asked for, but you didn't tell us what class you wanted to use or how to identify the div. I have updated my post to match your fiddle and made an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cs9asjhs/5/

Answer (score 0):

leave it as you have there, and then remove the class from the image with a specific ID:

```
$('#imageID').removeClass('posts');
```

or if you want all images within a specific DIV not to have that class:

```
$('#divID img').removeClass('posts');
```

Of course this depends if your code justifies doing it this way or not, this is the best "cheating" option if you have a lot of images and you want "to skip" a specific image or a bunch of them from the class assignment.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a custom attribute for the images you want to update:

`<img ... update="true">
('img[udpate="true"]').attr("src"," url...")`

Comment: This is not what OP asked. It's certain images in a *div*. This would clog your HTML too.